# Installing drywall in unfinished basement

Tags: drywall, concrete, basement

I have an unfinished basement with concrete walls and soft insulation bolted to it. I’d like to install some drywall to

Comment: I think you lost part of your question.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you accidentally hit post before you finished your question. Please edit it soon to fill in the rest or it will soon get flagged and removed. If it does, just post again, with the full question of course

Comment: Ok you have my permission.

Comment: The general answer is: Attach a wall frame (e.g., 2x4s with top & bottom plates bolted into the floor/ceiling) and attach the drywall to the frame. But too many variables to guess. More details + pictures would help.